# Read CSV into dictionary, using one column as dict index

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read this CSV file into a dictionary, so later I can quickly reference the data:

```
ID,Field1,Field2,Field3
1,DataF1,DataF2,DataF3
2,MoreDataF1,MoreDataF2,MoreDataF3
3,SomeMoreDataF1,SomeMoreDataF2,SomeMoreDataF3
```

The "ID" value is unique in the file, so I want to use that as the index for a dictionary, whose elements will be dictionaries with the other values. I want to be able to reference `myDict[2]["Field3"]` and retrieve `MoreDataF3`

What is the most *pythonic* way of achieving this?

I was able to do it like this:

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", mode='r') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile.readlines(), delimiter=',')

next(csv_reader)

myDict = {}
for row in csv_reader:
    myDict[int(row[0])] = {'Field1': row[1], 'Field2': row[2], 'Field3': row[3]}
```

But this quickly becomes horrible as the number of fields increase and can't be dynamic. I also played around with `DictReader` as well but it ended up being even more cumbersome. I believe there must be a better (and nicer way).

Comment: When you say `'Field1'`, `'Field2'` etc. do you really mean those literal names or names taken from elsewhere? You're skipping the header row so I'm assuming you really do mean those names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), and a dict comprehension.

```
import csv 
import pprint


with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    MyDict = {int(row.pop('ID')): row for row in reader}


pprint.pprint(MyDict)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'Field1': 'DataF1', 'Field2': 'DataF2', 'Field3': 'DataF3'},
 2: {'Field1': 'MoreDataF1', 'Field2': 'MoreDataF2', 'Field3': 'MoreDataF3'},
 3: {'Field1': 'SomeMoreDataF1',
     'Field2': 'SomeMoreDataF2',
     'Field3': 'SomeMoreDataF3'}}
```

The [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) removes the ID key/value pair from each row using [dict.pop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) to create the key, and uses the remainder of the row dict for the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it using pandas easily

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

print(csv)
```

outputs

```
python test.py
   ID          Field1          Field2          Field3
0   1          DataF1          DataF2          DataF3
1   2      MoreDataF1      MoreDataF2      MoreDataF3
2   3  SomeMoreDataF1  SomeMoreDataF2  SomeMoreDataF3
```

More info at https://pandas.pydata.org/